# How many misses/hits are there?

Tags: c, caching, assembly, mips, cpu

Let a `2^32` RAM memory and let a 2-way associative cache with 8 blocks (total). A block size is 4 words.

Since it's a 2-way associative and there are 8 blocks we know that `Index` length is 2 and the `Tag` length is `26`. Now,

> How many misses/hits are there for the following code? In runtime, the array is mapped to the address `0x2000` and `i` and `j` are stored in `$0`, `$1`, respectively.

```
char a[64];
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) 
      a[i] = '2';
```

I am confused since there are no reads at all in this code; all it does is writing to the memroy.

I'll be glad for an explanation

Comment: What is the word-size?

Comment: 32-bit (7 more to go)

Comment: How is the cache configured? (write-back/write-through/write-allocate) What does $x mean?

Comment: @Olaf, it does not mentioned in the question. For your second question, $x is a register (MIPS notation)

Comment: So you cannot answer this. If the cache is not write allocate, every write is a miss (assuming it has been flushed before, which would be another point to clarifiy). For write-through it makes no difference in actual timing. If that was an interview question, such enquiries are a good thing to get the asker into trouble himself.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something fundamental - Does the cache is used also when you **write** into memory?

Comment: That's why I'm asking.